# Implementation of NodeList

Tags: java, xml, xpath, implementation, nodelist

I implemented `NodeList` like this   :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class MyNodeList  implements NodeList{

    //// local member  ... 
    ArrayList<Node> arrayNode   = new ArrayList<Node>() ; 
    ////

    @Override
    public int getLength() {
        return arrayNode.size() ; 
    }

    @Override
    public Node item(int index) {
        return (arrayNode.get(index)).cloneNode(true); 
    }

    public void reverse ()  {
        Collections.reverse(arrayNode);
    }

    public void castNodeToMyNode (NodeList nodeListToCast) {
        int lenList = nodeListToCast.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < lenList; i++) {
            this.arrayNode.add(nodeListToCast.item(i)) ; 
        }
    }
    public void appendNodeList (NodeList nodeListToappend) {
        this.castNodeToMyNode(nodeListToappend)  ; 
    }

}
```

i have to do this cause i need the method `reverse`  - revese the order of the `NodeList` .

my question is  :  when is use `evaluate` function - `Object result = xpath.evaluate(expression, source,
                XPathConstants.NODESET);`

I want to set `source` argument as `item` of the `MyNodeList` implementation. Is it OK to set the `sourcec` as `myNodeAfterProbExp.item(indexOfNode)` when `myNodeAfterProbExp`
is an object of `MyNodeList` ?
I did something like this but I think it's disruptive for the execution of `evaluate`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're passing xpath.evaluate() a Node, why should it care that the Node came from your NodeList?

Comment: @MichaelKay you right it's node care  .. i had problem with the evalute  , now i add clone to the item method like the edited  source message and it work OK.